# Android Studio is auto importing fake.`package`.name.`for`.sync.R`. How to rectify that?

Tags: android, android-view, android-resources

I created a new module with a fragment view and a ViewModel. Every time a reference a view or resource attribute through view binding or getString(), it oddly auto imports `fake.`package`.name.`for`.sync.R`. Why is this happening? How to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Could fix it invalidating caches and restarting.

To do so, in Android studio top menu: `File-> invalidate caches -> invalidate and restart`

hope it helps